# In which scripture does the Shiva Mahimna stotra occur?

Tags: shiva, stotra, shiva-mahimna-stotra

For example, the Rudrashtakam occurs in the Ramacharitmanas, Uttar Kanda. I have been unable to find the scriptural source for the Shiva Mahimna stotra.

Comment: Its independent kriti of a gandharva named pushpadanta.

Comment: I know it is composed by Pushpadanta but where is it found in the scriptures? Like Rudrashtakam is composed by Lomash Rishi but it is recorded in Ramacharitmanas. So where is the Shiva Mahimna stotra recorded?

Comment: he was not rishi. There are several hymns that are not part of any scripture.

Comment: That could be it. So all hymns which occur in the scriptures like the vedas are composed by Rishis? There are no non-sages that find entry for their works in the scriptures?

Comment: not like that but scholars and devotees also write stotras which are not part of any grantha. Example sankaracharya madhwa ramanuja and several saints .

Comment: Thank you! If you write this as an answer, I will accept it.